# How can we return an object that is different from the method return type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I don't understand why we can pass `Customer` while the return type is `ActionResult<Customer>`. How can we return an object that is different from the method return type?

However, I understand for `Task<T>` used for asynchronous methods, because c# language provides such a feature internally.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Customer> Get(string id)
{
    Customer cust = db.Customers.Find(id);
    if (cust == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return cust;
}
```

Could you give me a simple example how to create our own `Wrapper<T>` to allow us to write something as follows?

```
public Wrapper<Foo> AnyMethod()
{
    return new Foo();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that first snippit compiles ?  Don't you need to write something like return Ok(cust); instead ?

Comment: You can also check [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0#actionresultt-type): "Implicit cast operators support the conversion of both T and ActionResult to ActionResult<T>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ActionResultOfT.cs) for ActionResult, you can see how it defines implicit conversion internally to allow it to wrap either some type T or ActionResult types. On similar lines, we can define a minimal Wrapper class like so:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
 private T _t;

 public Wrapper(T t)
 {
  _t = t;
 }

 public static implicit operator Wrapper<T>(T t)
 {
  return new Wrapper<T>(t);
 }
}
```

Comment: This trick made my mind blow. Thank you! By the way, I prefer making the `Wrapper` ctor private.